# Skip a specific number of characters, and return the desired output, using regex

Tags: regex, skip

Here is the code:

```
%2Fdl%2Fac8ee4c1b1ff6f713d3b19969d6c24e3%2F52d2eae9%2Fff2c0ea38304a00b01c3e573babcde109f
```

What I need is return in 3 separate regular expressions:

1. `ac8ee4c1b1ff6f713d3b19969d6c24e3` that's an easy one: `dl%2F(.*?)%2F`
2. `52d2eae9` -- currently I'm using dots (`.`) to skip the undesired chars, but looking for  a slicker way, if possible
3. `ff2c0ea38304a00b01c3e573babcde109` -- same as (2)

Comment: Why three sperate expressions? Why not one expression with three capturing groups?

Comment: Is %2F some sort of delimiter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I misunderstood you and you don't need three seperate *expressions*, then this one will capture all three items in a capturing group:

```
dl%2F(.+)%2F(.+)%2F(.+)
```

If there really is a need for three seperate expressions, then you may use them like

1. `dl%2F(.+)%2F`
2. `dl%2F.+%2F(.+)%2F`
3. `dl%2F.+%2F.+%2F(.+)`
   or
   `.*%2F(.+?)$` (Note: `$` marks the end of the input)

Comment: Thank you! I need 3 separate regex b/c the addon I'm working with only takes in the 1st one returned!, but it's great to know you it can be done! Cheers!

Comment: A slight correction: This dl%2F(.+)%2F returns ac8ee4c1b1ff6f713d3b19969d6c24e3%2F52d2eae9 instead of ac8ee4c1b1ff6f713d3b19969d6c24e3 :( This will do it: dl%2F(.*?)%2F Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
$ perl -lne 'print join "\n", /dl%2F(.*?)(?:%2F)(.*?)(?:%2F)(.*)/' file
ac8ee4c1b1ff6f713d3b19969d6c24e3
52d2eae9
ff2c0ea38304a00b01c3e573babcde109f
```

Or fetching only one element :

```
$ perl -lne 'print join "", (/dl%2F(.*?)(?:%2F)(.*?)(?:%2F)(.*)/)[2]' file
ff2c0ea38304a00b01c3e573babcde109f
```

Or if the delimiter and positions are stable & using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
$ awk -F'%2F' '{print $3, $4, $5}' OFS="\n" file
ac8ee4c1b1ff6f713d3b19969d6c24e3
52d2eae9
ff2c0ea38304a00b01c3e573babcde109f
```

Comment: Thank you! I need 3 separate regex b/c the addon I'm working with only takes in the 1st one returned!, but it's great to know you it can be done! -Cheers!